# Field oriented control of brushless motors

Tags: otherservos, pid, brushless-motor

If I was controlling a normal brushed motor as a servo, I would measure the motor's position, and adjust the PWM signal to control the voltage. This way I could achieve a precise velocity/position profile if my control was good enough.

```
pwm_duty = CalcPID(motor_position - target_position);
```

When doing Field Oriented Control (FOC) of a brushless motor, there are two parameters I can control: The voltage angle, and the voltage magnitude. There are three things I can measure, the current angle and magnitude, and the rotor position.

I want to achieve a precise velocity/position profile including good control down to zero speed and reverse.

Question: how can I calculate the correct voltage field angle (or phase lead) and magnitude?  Do I need two PID algorithms?

```
phase_lead  = CalcPID_1( ... );
voltage_mag = CalcPID_2( ... );
```

Assume I can take any reasonable measurements of the motor state, including rotor position and winding current.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the most efficient thing to do is to maintain a 90 degree phase lead, and adjust your voltage magnitude for control.  You'll probably want to have an inner current loop, wrapped by the actual position loop.